Cannot consume the context value from the App Component in Reactjs
I am trying to create a GlobalContext for my application but for some reason I am unable to consume the context in my App component.
Context/index.js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalState = ({ child }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("hi from context");
  return <GlobalContext.Provider value={val}>{child}</GlobalContext.Provider>;
};

main.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { GlobalState } from "./Context/index.jsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <GlobalState>
        <App />
      </GlobalState>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

App.jsx
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/index";
import { GlobalContext } from "./Context/index";

function App() {
  const x = useContext(GlobalContext);
  console.log("globaldata", x);
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
        <Route exact path="/recipe-item/:id" element={<Details />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I should be able to consume the GlobalContext from my App Component but my application is breaking. And there is no console logging. Why is that? Do I need any modifications?

are you seeing an error? your code looks fine.

@DevonRay it is not rendering anything. and there is no log of 'x'

Ahh i see whats up:
You've used child instead of children.
export const GlobalState = ({ children }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("hi from context");
  return <GlobalContext.Provider value={val}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>;
};



Thanks! It worked. Also, I was wondering, what is the difference? And what is the significance of passing any props to GlobalState anyway?
